# How to add active class using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set the active class by onclick function.

when I click A (parent li) the li tags are active.
But when I click siblings li i.e A11 are active while parent li tags are inactive, **the following problems ocur**:

all the siblings and parent li tags are hidden

I want to display siblings li tags along with parent li tags

**My code:**

```
<div>
    <ul id="o_shop_collapse_category">
        <li class="active"> A
            <ul id="category">
                <li>A11</li>
                <li>A12</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>B
            <ul id="category">
                <li> B12</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() { 
        $('#o_shop_collapse_category li:not(.active)').hide();
        $('#category li').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please create a working snippet demonstrating your issue.

Comment: You can use codepen, jsfiddle, jsbin etc to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see *in the snippet below*, the bunch of code you provided is not enough for us to answer you. The `li` elements are not even clickable, for us to see the behaviour you describe.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $('#o_shop_collapse_category li:not(.active)').hide();
  $('#category li').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="o_shop_collapse_category">
    <li class="active"> A
      <ul id="category">
        <li>A11</li>
        <li>A12</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>B
      <ul id="category">
        <li> B12</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```